# How do I access the details for java.sql.SQLExceptions generated by slick?

Tags: java, sqlite, scala, slick

When the user tries to create a database object without a unique name, I want to display a custom error message. We are using SQLite and when an insert violates the uniqueness constraint we get a `java.sql.SQLException`.

The `ex.getMessage` output is:

```
 "java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (column name is not unique)"
```

But `getErrorCode()` returns `0` and `getSQLState()` returns null. I expect the `getErrorCode()` result to be `19`. [Sqlite Error Codes](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html)

How can I identify this specific exception without parsing the string looking for `SQLITE_CONSTRAINT`?

Comment: Did you tried getNextException() ? If it doesn' contain more exceptions then probably you can't get your code 19 as jdbc driver is not populating this field

Comment: Yes, getNextException is null. :(

Comment: what return   getSQLState()?

Comment: @pL4Gu33 it returns null.